# Heroku "State changed from starting to down Stopping all processes with SIGTERM"

Tags: node.js, heroku

After booting up my Node.js Heroku app with this Procfile:

```
web: node www/main.js
```

I used to get:

> Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within
>   60 seconds of launch

So I have changed my Procfile to a generic command to get around this, following from [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile#declaring-process-types), using:

```
start: node www/main.js
```

And I am still getting a shut down after 60 seconds. This is the error(s) now:

> 2015-01-20T13:04:01.452819+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from
>   up to starting
>       2015-01-20T13:04:02.728905+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to down
>       2015-01-20T13:04:03.434251+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `node www/main.js`
>       2015-01-20T13:04:03.874370+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
>       2015-01-20T13:04:05.188100+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 143
>       2015-01-20T13:04:05.930916+00:00 app[worker.1]: [Tue Jan 20 2015 13:04:05 GMT+0000 (UTC)] INFO Connecting...
>       2015-01-20T13:04:06.837197+00:00 app[worker.1]: Welcome to Slack. You are @derpy of
>       2015-01-20T13:04:06.837559+00:00 app[worker.1]: You are in: #general
>       2015-01-20T13:04:06.837637+00:00 app[worker.1]: As well as:
>       2015-01-20T13:04:06.837739+00:00 app[worker.1]: You have 13 unread messages
>       2015-01-20T13:04:07.526373+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At least one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of
>   SIGTERM
>       2015-01-20T13:04:07.526508+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Stopping remaining processes with SIGKILL

I am using https://github.com/slackhq/node-slack-client and have not adapted the code too much. I have tried all the usual things and now I'm asking for help.

The other weird thing is that the Slack bot connects and is running perfectly for those 60 seconds.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`socket = io.listen(process.env.PORT);`

Do this in your `main.js` file, and revert back to web: node `www/main.js`

Comment: @Will heroku sets the port you must use on the env variable `PORT`