# Stopping all processes with SIGTERM

Tags: python, heroku, bots, discord, discord.py

My heroku applications all stopped working by giving me this error in logs
why? and any solution? i have not edited anything or changed anything in my code or procfile or any other files
[procfile attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQSP0.png)

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: @mishsx I assume it's the title. "Stopping all processes with SIGTERM".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Heroku "State changed from starting to down Stopping all processes with SIGTERM"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28046190/heroku-state-changed-from-starting-to-down-stopping-all-processes-with-sigterm)

Comment: Could you post your `Procfile` ?

Comment: @mishsx This won't work, since it's for `node.js`, not `python`. With `node.js`, you need a `web` dyno, with python, you need a `worker` one.

Comment: this worked till today morning and i dint change any files