# State Changed from up to Crashed ( Discord App Won't Start ) , and yes i use a start script and everything is right

Tags: heroku, discord.js, heroku-cli

2022-05-27T00:41:10.751190+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-27T00:41:10.761682+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-05-27T00:41:12.597341+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `: node .`
2022-05-27T00:41:13.215607+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-05-27T00:41:13.579455+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 0
2022-05-27T00:41:13.649880+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed
2022-05-27T00:41:45.366307+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2022-05-27T00:41:45.457887+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-05-27T00:41:45.474285+00:00 app[web.1]: Error waiting for process to terminate: No child processes
2022-05-27T00:41:45.610972+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 22

Answer (score 0):

For python,
Simply, use `gunicorn` to easen the burden.

- Within the project directory, with the virtual environment activated, install `gunicorn` as follows:

```
pip install gunicorn
```

- If you're using `pipenv` you can try:
  `pipenv install gunicorn`
- Update the `requirements.txt` file to include the new installed `gunicorn` module by running:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

- Update the `Procfile` as follows:

```
web: gunicorn your_django_project_name.wsgi --log-file -
```

N.B:
There should be space between the `web:` and `gunicorn` as well as between `--log-file` and the `-` next to it.

Lastly, add, commit and push the changes

Answer (score 0):

For `js` devs,

Make sure the `Procfile` looks like:

```
web: npm start
```

**THEN**

try this solution **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452019/9448032)**

Comment: i tried and changed the start script too , i need to run all the bot's files so i need to use [ node . ] but it's crashing with the same reason & i'm sure code isn't wrong because i locally hosted it

Comment: Have you tried this solution [here?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29452019/9448032)